# search and count specific phrases with special characters in text files

Tags: python, string, findall

I have a list of search phrases where some are single words, some are multiple words, some have a hyphen in between them, and others may have both parentheses and hyphens. I'm trying to process a directory of text files and search for 100+ of these phrases, and then count occurrences.

It seems like the code below works in 2.7x python until it hits the hyphenated search phrases. I observed some unexpected counts on some text files for at least one of the hyphenated search phrases.

```
kwlist = ['phraseone', 'phrase two', 'phrase-three', 'phrase four (a-b-c) abc', 'phrase five abc', 'phrase-six abc abc']
for kws in kwlist:
    s_str = kws
    kw = re.findall(r"\b" + s_str +r"\b", ltxt)
    count = 0
    for c in kw:
        if c == s_str:
            count += 1
    output.write(str(count))
```

Is there a better way to handle the range of phrases in the search, or any improvements I can make to my algorithm?

Comment: can you please provide what exactly does not work? do you get an error message? please add to your post those unexpected results.

Comment: There are no error messages. So far, the issue is when it gets to something like 'phrase-six abc abc' in a text file, it has inflated counts for at least one text file it is searching. Still checking the others.

Comment: Maybe provide the text passages that contain the phrase you think is counted wrong and the actual phrases. This seems more like a problem with your regex usage.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this with what I would call a `pythonic` one-liner.

We don't need to bother with using a `regex`, as we can use the built-in [`.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) method, which will from the documentation:

> **`string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]])`**
>
> Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s[start:end]. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices.

So all we need to do is `sum` up the occurrences of each keyword in `kwlist` in the `string` `ltxt`. This can be done with a `list-comprehension`:

```
output.write(str(sum([ltxt.count(kws) for kws in kwlist])))
```

---

**Update**

As pointed out in [`@voiDnyx's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932542/search-and-count-specific-phrases-with-special-characters-in-text-files/46933165?noredirect=1#comment80813473_46933165), the above solution `writes` the `sum` of **all** the `counts`, not for each individual keyword.

If you want the individual keywords outputted, you can just `write` each one individually from the `list`:

```
counts = [ltxt.count(kws) for kws in kwlist]
for cnt in counts:
    output.write(str(cnt))
```

This will work, but if you wanted to get silly and put it all in one-line, you could potentially do:

```
[output.write(str(ltxt.count(kws))) for kws in kwlist]
```

Its up to you, hope this helps! **:)**

---

If you need to match word boundaries, then yes the only way to do so would be to use the `\b` in a `regex`. This doesn't mean that you cant still do it in one line:

[output.write(str(len(re.findall(r'\b'+re.escape(kws)+r'\b'))) for kws in kwlist]

Note how the `re.escape` is necessary, as the keyword may contain `special` characters.

Comment: I think counts for each kws are wanted, you are summing up the counts of all kws if i am not misstaken? So basically just dont sum up anything and just return/print the list of counts.

Comment: @voiDnyx Ah yes, my mistake, I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code and the one-line. I tried it and it found parts of the keywords and full matches, but not only full matches of the keywords. I also scoured the script and found that there was a missing quote in a very long keyword list. It threw off the counts by a field in my output. So, unless there is another option, it appears using kw = re.findall(r"\b" + s_str +r"\b", ltxt) is the way to find the full phrases from the keyword list unless there is an alternative?

Comment: I have updated the answer now with a `regex` solution